# Failed to build module swiftlang-1103.0.32.1 clang-1103.0.32.29

Tags: swift, clang

Integrating the quickpaySDK with the help of Cocoa Pod, tried in both the Xcode12.2 and Xcode12.3

Failed to build module 'QuickPaySDK' from its module interface; the compiler that produced it, 'Apple Swift version 5.2 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.1 clang-1103.0.32.29)', may have used features that aren't supported by this compiler, 'Apple Swift version 5.3.2 (swiftlang-1200.0.45 clang-1200.0.32.28)'

Answer (score 0):

Disable Bitcode. It would be OK.

Comment: Well, then the cause of problem is the SDK. You can choose either of these options:

1/ You raise an issue on their GitHub and wait for the response.

2/ You fork their source and update the stuff and make a pull request.

3/ Back to Xcode 11 and compile after disable hold the bitcode.